# PostgreSQL merge recursive query and JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, recursive-query

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_employee_team
(
  employee_id int,
  teams_id int
);

INSERT INTO tbl_employee_team 
VALUES 
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4);

CREATE TABLE tbl_team_list_serv
(
  service_id int,
  team_id int
);

INSERT INTO tbl_team_list_serv
VALUES
(7, 2),
(9, 3),
(10, 4);

CREATE TABLE tbl_service
(
  id int,
  parent int
);

INSERT INTO tbl_service
VALUES
(5, null),
(6, 5),
(7, 6),

(8, null),
(9, 8),

(10, null);
```

For the sake of simplicity I declared:

`1` as employee_id

`2, 3, 4` as team_id

`5 -> 6 -> 7` as service (5 is the main service)

`8 -> 9` (8 is the main service)

`10` (10 is the main service)

To retrieve the services the employee belongs to I query

```
SELECT ls.service_id FROM tbl_team_list_serv ls 
JOIN tbl_employee_team t ON ls.team_id=t.teams_id WHERE t.employee_id = 1
```

To get the main service from the services I use

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS 
(
   SELECT id, parent, 1 AS level
   FROM tbl_service
   WHERE id = 7 /*(here's I need to assign to every id from the JOIN)*/
  
   UNION

   SELECT tbl_service.id, tbl_service.parent, r.level + 1 AS level
   FROM tbl_service
      JOIN r
          ON r.parent = tbl_service.id
)


SELECT id FROM r WHERE r.level = (SELECT max(level) FROM r)
```

My question is how do I merge the two queries?

Based on the data above I want to finally get a list of ids which is in this case:

```
5, 8, 10
```

Also, I want my recursive query to return the last row (I don't think that the solution with level is elegant)

SQLFiddle can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c0724/37)

Thanks in advance

Comment: /*(here's I need to assign to every id from the JOIN)*/     Question: Which ids you need here?

Comment: Retrieved ids from the 1st JOIN. `7, 9, 10` in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like you already did most of the work for this question.  This is just a matter of the following tweaks:

- Putting the logic for the first query in the anchor part of the CTE.
- Adding the original service id as a column to remember the hierarchy.
- Tweaking the final logic to get one row per original service.

As a query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE r AS  (
     SELECT ls.service_id as id, s.parent, 1 as level, ls.service_id as orig_service_id
     FROM tbl_team_list_serv ls JOIN
          tbl_employee_team t
          ON ls.team_id = t.teams_id JOIN
          tbl_service s 
          ON ls.service_id = s.id
     WHERE t.employee_id = 1
     UNION ALL
     SELECT s.id, s.parent, r.level + 1 AS level, r.orig_service_id
     FROM tbl_service s JOIN
          r
          ON r.parent = s.id
   )
SELECT r.id
FROM (SELECT r.*,
             MAX(level) OVER (PARTITION BY orig_service_id) as max_level
      FROM r
     ) r
WHERE r.level = max_level;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b560f8a2f670f955ac258fda0bac3068) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you very much, your query did the trick.